# Why is the wrong CloseReason generated?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am working on a WindowsForms project in VB.NET at the .NET Framework 4.6. The tool shoul log for what reason it got closed and prevent user closing. In other projects with older version of the tool this works fine. But in this project, I always get "UserClosing" as reason when I kill the app with the task manager.

Why doesn't it show "TaskManagerClosing" as in previous projects?

Comment: ['End Task' in Task Manager always sets CloseReason.UserClosing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22251027/7444103) -- Comments here: [VB.NET always gives a closereason as userclosing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57824315/7444103)

Comment: Its not always UserClosing. I added a hidden "Exit" button, which calls ```Application.Exit()```. This gets the ExitCode ApplicationExitCall